# Import Maven projects in Eclipse from Git repo

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

**How do I import Maven projects in Eclipse from Git repository?**

My setup:

- Eclipse Neon
- EGit with SSH, using built-in PPK auth
- EGit connector for project import installed
- Git repository with 120+ Maven projects

I finally managed to clone my 16+ GB Git repository. Now I wonder, how am I supposed to work with my projects in Eclipse.

In Git Repository view, I see a folder called 'Working Tree' containing all the project folders. Having the EGit connector installed, the context menu contains an entry 'Import Maven Projects...'. There I selected the `pom.xml` files of my Maven projects (no other file types are shown) and after a while Eclipse has created projects in the Project Explorer view accordingly.

However, the projects only contain the `pom.xml` file and none of the actual code files or folders.

Did I miss something? How do I create Maven projects automatically in Eclipse for all the Maven projects that are in my Git repo?

Comment: Can you clarify your description of the Git Repository view? As I read it, you are stating that all your repositories are found under a single Working Tree. Is this a single large Git repo that has your projects as sub-modules? I would expect that each project's repository would be shown in the Repository view with its own Working Tree.

Comment: Correct, all projects are shown in a single working tree with their own folders. This is a bridged SVN repository.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The process you described should have worked. Have you verified that
your project folders contain more than just a POM file? If so, try importing via
`File->Import->Maven->Existing MavenProjects` using `Browse...` to navigate to your repository's
directory. As before, you should see a list of POMs from which you can choose what projects to
import. Essentially it is the same wizard as you selected from the context menu, but sometimes what appears to
be the same works differently depending on how it is invoked.

Comment: While I do use `git svn` from time to time, it has always been
on a project-by-project basis, rather than a full repository clone. I didn't even realize it was
possible to clone a complete SVN repository. I tried firing up an old SVN repo to test this but had no
luck. Without other information, I'm concerned that you now have one large (i.e. 16GB+)
repository that tracks changes to a myriad of projects, when each project should have its own repo.

Comment: See [Practical tips for using Git with large Subversion repositories](http://www.janosgyerik.com/practical-tips-for-using-git-with-large-subversion-repositories/) which is what I use when working with Git & SVN. My apologies for these multiple comments. I don't consider them answers.

Comment: Thank you, but eventually it turned out, that running the same importer in Git view again, solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, it turned out that Eclipse did a faulty import on first attempt. In despair I deleted all projects that were created by the importer (without deleting the files on disk), then I ran the import again using the context menu entry **Import Maven Projects...** of the Git view.

This time all projects were created fully, not just containing the `pom.xml` file but all Java packages, source files and additional binary resources as well.

I'm not sure if the first attempt to import just failed or if the fact, that I eventually ran the importer twice, fixed the problem. But maybe my experiences will still help someone else:

**In case of similar problems, try deleting the empty projects and simply run the import again.**